# SQL count not showing 0 result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table member_asrama and asrama. I want count row row_asrama with condition, but the result not showing result 0 from count.

Table member_asrama:

```
id    asrama_id    period_id    
1     1            1
```

Table asrama

```
id    name       
1     A
2     B
```

My query

```
SELECT asrama.id,asrama.name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM asrama
left join member_asrama
on asrama.id = member_asrama.`asrama_id` 
where member_asrama.`period_id` = 1
group by asrama.id
```

Result

```
asrama.id asrama.name cnt
1          A           1
```

I want result

```
asrama.id asrama.name cnt
1          A           1
2          B           0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the condition needs to be in the `ON` clause:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(ma.asrama_id) as cnt
from asrama a left join
     member_asrama ma
     on a.id = ma.asrama_id and
        ma.period_id = 1
group by a.id, a.name;
```

Note other changes:

- `COUNT()` counts a column from `member_asrama`.  That allows `0` in the results.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Backticks make the query harder to write and read -- and they are not necessary.
- I included both columns in the `GROUP BY`.  Technically, this is not necessary if `id` is a primary/unique key.  However, it is a good habit if you are learning SQL.